# Showdialog Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm trying to put showdialog after finish this animation. When i click the button, the showdialog opens, but i want to open showdialog after finish the animation.
look my animation code:

```
  btngirar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
            angle = r.nextInt(10000) + 360;
            RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, angle,
                    RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            rotate.setFillAfter(true);
            rotate.setDuration(4000);
            rotate.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

            ivgarrafa.startAnimation(rotate); //ivgarrafa is the image that rotates     

}    
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
rotate.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {    
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {  

}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

//show your dialog here

}
});
```